# Can an persistent HTTP client send more than one request at a time?

Tags: http, sockets, connection

I am writing a HTTP proxy server and I noticed that many clients use the "Connection: Keep-Alive" header to keep a persistent connection. Is it possible that the client sends another HTTP request before the server processes the first?

For example, the client sends "GET / HTTP/1.1" but before the server has a chance to respond, the client sends "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1". Is that possible? Or will the client pause for the response before sending the second request?

Also, when using a persistent connection, is it safe to assume all requests through that connection will have the same "Host: " header?

Comment: [HTTP pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining#Implementation_in_web_proxies), which is different from simply persistent connections

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for the client to pipeline requests.  (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining).

Turning your last question around... it would not be safe for a client to assume that requests to multiple hosts would be served by a single pipeline.  There may be no specs that directly address your question on the Host: header, but it's a safe bet they'll be the same.

Comment: I don't understand why "it would not be safe for a client to assume that requests to multiple hosts would be served by a single pipeline". It is the client's choice to use a single pipeline!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the term "HTTP pipelining". I am writing the server, not the client, so I want to handle any weird quarks that the client will throw at me. So I are you saying I should try to handle the case that a persistent connection will try to connect to a different host?

Comment: Yes, I am saying that, even if I guess few or no browser behave like that today.

Comment: The Host request-header field specifies the Internet host and port number of the resource being requested, so if they're different, then it implies different hosts and/or different TCP ports.  It's a natural constraint.

Answer (score 7):

"Also, when using a persistent connection, is it safe to assume all requests through that connection will have the same "Host: " header?"

I don't think so, see [HTTPbis P1, Section 2.2](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-17.html#rfc.section.2.2):

> Recipients MUST consider every message in a connection in isolation; because HTTP is a stateless protocol, it cannot be assumed that two requests on the same connection are from the same client or share any other common attributes. In particular, intermediaries might mix requests from different clients into a single server connection. Note that some existing HTTP extensions (e.g., [RFC4559]) violate this requirement, thereby potentially causing interoperability and security problems.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first question:

> Is it possible that the client sends another HTTP request before the server processes the first?

I believe that yes, it can be possible (perhaps I am wrong, I remembered having read that a couple of years ago; the definitive answer is in the HTTP protocol specifications). But I don't understand why you are asking. Also, the client can open several TCP connections at once to the same HTTP server. And of course you have many simultaneous clients.

About the second question

> Also, when using a persistent connection, is it safe to assume all requests through that connection will have the same "Host: " header?

I believe it is usually the case, but I won't assume that to be certain. I could imagine that some clever HTTP clients, recognizing that two URL with different Host: headers share the same IP, could re-use the same connection.

But I don't understand why you are asking. Persistent HTTP connections have been invented to minimize the TCP connections which are costly, and the two questions you are asking are an extreme point on that. Perhaps few HTTP clients are doing what you describe today.

And you should be strict on what you send (w.r.t. standard conformance), but flexible on what you accept receiving.

Comment: I am asking because I am trying to write a generic HTTP proxy server and I want to handle anything a client throws at me.

Comment: But I don't see why that matters to you. A robust HTTP proxy would suppose a yes to Q1 and a no to Q2.